# Identifying / visualising the most informative data source or combination of data sources

Tags: data-visualization, information-theory

I have observations on the status (say, dead = 0, alive = 1) of a number of subjects as recorded in three distinct data sources at the same point in time:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Subject | Source1 | Source2 | Source3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       | 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 0       | 1       | 1       |
| 3       | 1       | 0       | 1       |
| 4       | 1       | 1       | 0       |
| 5       | 1       | 0       | 1       |
| n       | …       | …       | …       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way to determine which data source or combination of data sources is most informative with regard to the subjects likely true status? This is no prior information about the reliability of any of the sources.

Comment: What is mutual information? (for ranking each source separately regarding their information about the true status)